# Absolute value proof with epsilon

Tags: absolute-value

I'm having trouble with this proof. any hints would be greatly appreciated!

If $x$ is a positive real number, show that for some $\epsilon$ $>0, $ then $y\in \Bbb{R}$ is positive if $|(x-y)|< $ $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints:

All the $y$ satisfies $|x-y|<\epsilon$ is the set $(x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon)$

Comment: I'm not quite understanding where you got that from?

Answer (score 0):

Hins. Take: $$\epsilon=x$$. then got that $y>0$